# Programatical proxy support in Spring WebSockets' SockJsClient

Tags: java, spring, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I'm developing a tiny Java 15 application which connects to a Spring Boot based infrastructure using STOMP over WebSockets. Basically this is a no-brainer but unfortunately corporate proxy settings are very disturbing. Since it could be possible that the corporate security policies require different proxies for different applications it should be possible to configure this programatically.

As said previously the application is written in Java 15 and the pom.xml where I referred spring-websockets and spring-messaging looks like this:

```xml
<!-- ... -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- ... -->
```

With other applications where I used standard Java HttpClients it was really simple. In this cases it is sufficient to configure the HttpClient like this:

```java
HttpClient.newBuilder().proxy( ProxySelector.of( new InetSocketAddress( proxyHostAddr, proxyPort ) ) ).authenticator( proxyAuthenticator ).build();
```

Because WebSockets are indeed based on the HTTP protocol I assumed that there is a place in the Spring universe where I just can get the underlying HttpClient (if this is used of course) and update its proxy settings.

With the following snipped I initialize a very basic STOMP client:

```java
// Set up WebSocket connection transports (different ways to communicate with a WS server)
List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>( 2 );
transports.add( new WebSocketTransport( new StandardWebSocketClient() ) );
transports.add( new RestTemplateXhrTransport() );

this.stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient( new SockJsClient( transports ) );
```

I wasn't able to find out where I can intercept or implement a interface or something like that to ONLY exchange the proxy settings.

There was only a single way how I managed to get this running: When building my application as .jar I can tell the JVM which proxies to use by calling the JAR like this:

```bash
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8081 -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8081 -jar myJar.jar
```

Since I don't know the proxy settings at each customer this solution is not acceptable and it also leads to the situation that ALL networking stuff inside this JVM instance is lead through the proxy.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
As I'm debugging for hours now I found out something new: The underlying WebSocket implementation is `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer`. Inside this class the system proxy is retrieved using the `ProxySelector.getDefault()` call. Unfortunately this class doesn't offer any method to override the way of how the proxies are gathered. In the worst case I have to copy this whole 800-line class and just replace the particular piece of code. But I feel uncomfortable doing this. Maybe someone in the audience here has a clue.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while working on something similar and the answer to [Spring WebSocket(Stomp)Client proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159859/spring-websocketstompclient-proxy) seemed to cover most of it, but used an older `HttpClientBuilder`.

In short, passing in a custom `RestTemplate` with your desired proxy configuration, to the `RestTemplateXhrTransport` constructor.

```
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClients;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.HttpHost;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

...
transports.add(new RestTemplateXhrTransport(getRestTemplate()));
...

private RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    HttpHost myProxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort);
    // Proxy can be configured as needed.
    CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = HttpClients.custom().setProxy(myProxy).build();
    
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    factory.setHttpClient(closeableHttpClient);
    return new RestTemplate(factory);
}
```